# Centering an image in navbar while maintaining 100% navbar width

Tags: css

I am trying to center my image in between two UL tags, but it's not functioning as I would like. I tried various sources from this website and I can't find one specifically with the answer to this one problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFD4DB;
}
#navbar {
  height: 55px;
  width: 80%;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FF405E;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9B5E68;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff9baa+31,ffadae+93 */
  background: #ff9baa;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff9baa 31%, #ffadae 93%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff9baa 31%, #ffadae 93%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff9baa 31%, #ffadae 93%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff9baa', endColorstr='#ffadae', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
#navbar > ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#navbar > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #9B5E68;
}
#lgo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img id="lgo" src="http://i.imgur.com/niYdlBv.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: paste you code please.

Comment: What did you try so far? paste your code

Comment: My apologies, I accidently pressed the enter key while typing and it submitted the question. Anyway, I posted the html and js.fiddle leading to the css.

Comment: How is it that you would like it to function?

Comment: With the text centered in the navigation bar with my image in the middle. Please if you're gonna write it for me then comment what you did so that I can learn from it. I don't want to be a leech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that for you!

I added attributes for all ul's.

```
#navbar ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Then I changed a bit in the HTML file. In the middle where the picture sits, go paste:

```
<ul>
    <img id="lgo" src="http://i.imgur.com/niYdlBv.png">
</ul>
```

Yep, now add this to the #lgo:

```
#lgo {
    height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope I could help you!

[Here's the Pen!](http://codepen.io/callmeniko/pen/ZWemGL)

Comment: Thanks for the comment niko! https://jsfiddle.net/tt411ho6/3/ I found that it didn't do exactly what we were intending. I did as stated and I understand where you're going.

Comment: Not bad, I reloaded my fiddle and got the same results cheers.